# When using vbs to search folder, open file, run macro personal.xlsb stays open so files cannot be moved

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, macros

I'm using vbs to search a folder for a filename containing "OPS" and "Eve" and calling a macro from Personal.xlsb, save as, close. The script runs fine and does what I need it to but Personal.xlsb stays open in the background and won't allow me to move/delete/etc. the files unless I stop the process via the task manager. This is bothersome because doing so closes all other open Excel workbooks. Any help is appreciated. General VBS tips concerning the code below are also welcome.

```
Dim app, fso, file, fName, wb, dir, wb2, shell, searchFileNameOPS, searchFileNameEvents

dir = "C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test\"
searchFileNameOPS = "OPS"
searchFileNameEvents = "Event"

Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set wb2 = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ntunstall\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB")

For Each file In fso.GetFolder(dir).Files
  If InStr(file.Name, searchFileNameOPS) = 1 Then
    fName = fso.GetBaseName(file)

    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(file)
    app.Application.Visible = False
    app.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    app.Run wb2.Name & "!Main"

    app.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs dir & fName & ".xlsm", 52
  End If

  If InStr(file.Name, searchFileNameEvents) = 1 Then
    fName = fso.GetBaseName(file)

    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(file) 
    app.Application.Visible = False
    app.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    app.Run wb2.Name & "!Events"

    app.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs dir & fName & ".xlsm", 52
  End If
Next

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Is this VBScript or VBA? You state you are using VBS, but the code seems to be VBA (VBS ignores `DIM` and every variable is a variant).

Comment: What happens if you try to close the open workbooks with the [`.Close`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838613.aspx) method?

Comment: I think its VBS(basically a text file saved as script4.vbs) but maybe I don't know the difference.  Could you elaborate on `.Close`?

Comment: Its VBSCript then. :)  To use the .Close method, use it ion the workbook you want to close: `wb.Close` or `wb2.Close` (not sure which XLS file is staying open)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other COM objects instances of MS Office applications are not automatically terminated when your script terminates. The workbooks also won't magically close themselves. You need to do it yourself.

Other improvements:

- `Visible` and `DisplayAlerts` are properties of the application object, so you need to set them only once, not for every workbook opened.
- Don't construct paths via string concatenation. Use the [`BuildPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt.aspx) method instead. It handles path separators automatically, so you don't need to bother adding or removing backslashes to/from path components.
- Instead of using separate `If` statements you could use an n-way conditional (`If..ElseIf`).
- Your two `If` blocks do practically the same thing with only minor differences, so you may want to put that code in a procedure and pass the differing values as parameters.
- `WScript.Quit` at the end of a script is useless. It's only necessary if you want to exit from the script (usually with a non-zero exit code) on some condition.

```vb
dir = "C:\Users\ntunstall\Desktop\test"

Sub RunMacroAndSaveAs(file, macro)
  Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(file)
  app.Run wb2.Name & "!" & macro
  wb.SaveAs fso.BuildPath(file.ParentFolder, fso.GetBaseName(file) & ".xlsm"), 52
  wb.Close
End Sub

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
app.Visible       = False
app.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb2 = app.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB")

For Each file In fso.GetFolder(dir).Files
  If InStr(file.Name, "OPS") = 1 Then
    RunMacroAndSaveAs file, "Main"
  ElseIf InStr(file.Name, "Event") = 1 Then
    RunMacroAndSaveAs file, "Events"
  End If
Next

app.Quit
```

If you don't exit from the script right after terminating the Excel instance you may also want to add `Set app = Nothing` to remove the reference to the application object. Otherwise the Excel process will keep lingering until the script eventually terminates, thus automatically removing the reference.

Comment: Thank you! This takes care of the background process that was holding me up. However, when I tested this it will run for all files containing "Event" but will only run 1 file(out of 3 in the folder) that contains "OPS". The "OPS" files and "Main" macro are a lot larger than the "Event" files and macro, if that means anything.

Comment: Your code only runs the macros if the filename begins with the given keywods, not if it contains the keyword anywhere else in the filename. If you want the latter change `=1` to `>0`.

Comment: Same result. The files do start with "OPS" but I tried it anyway. I'm using a batch file to run the script and the error is "The remote procedure call failed.".

Comment: Is that the complete error message? Where exactly does the error come from? The VBScript or the VBA code?

Comment: The error line in cmd reads: "C:\Users\tunstall\Desktop\test\script5.vbs(4, 3) (null): The remote procedure call failed."

Comment: So, what is the statement in line 4 of that script?

Comment: The script(script5.vbs) consists of your answer above with the addition of `wScript.Close` just before `app.Quit` and I filled in the path for personal.xlsb.

Comment: Nothing in the code I posted would raise an error like that. Please verify that the error doesn't come from one of the macros. If the error comes from a macro please edit your question and show the code of that macro, otherwise edit your question and show the modified VBScript code that produces the error.